# Shell script which takes the input and path of a file and then chmod it in 775

Tags: bash, shell

Shell script which takes the input and path of a file and then chmod it in 775

can someone show me some exampels?

Comment: Of course you have searched Internet with `chmod example` and found a lot information. What part is giving you  problems?

Answer (score 1):

I would work on phrasing your question a bit better...but below is an example you could use I believe.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please enter the path and filename...Example=/var/tmp/test.txt    #:" location
while [[ -f ! ${location} ]] ; do
  echo "File not found... Try again."
  read -p "Please enter the path and filename... Example=/var/tmp/test.txt    #:" location
done
chmod 755 ${location}
```

This script prompts the user for a path and file name. If the path/filename does not exist, then the user will continue to be asked until he types in a correct path/file. The permissions will then be changed.